# Adding Java class to Oracle database by SQL Developer - compilation error

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have technical issue with my database. In SQL Developer there is an option designed to add Java code to database. But when I try to add my code, error message appears (shown below). Do you have any idea where I can find info about what comilation error is this? Some log maybe? And what are the requiments for good Java class? I tried to add Hello World code and it worked fine.

Error message:  https://s4.postimg.org/if3ip9zfh/screenshot000213.jpg

Comment: Can you post the Java code here?  How could we tell what compilation error is ?

Comment: That's my question. Where can I find info about compilation error? Code works fine in Java IDE, but I can't load it to database. That's the problem.

Comment: Can't see your screenshot, perhaps writing the actual error would help

Comment: "Error in source code: Success with compilation error". And that's it. No more info about error. That's why I'm asking.
You should connect to the db and on the left panel where you have tables, views indexes etc. there is also Java item. Then you have to click "Load Java" and when you insert your code this error appears. :)

Comment: what @westman379 said - you should find your class in the db tree in the Java node, and the errors would be visible there. You could also query 'SELECT * FROM USER_ERRORS'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It'll probably be easier to create a class via a script with DDL.

We do it like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "IP6Address" AS
import java.math.BigInteger;
public class IP6Address
{ 
  ... -- whatever
}
/
```

We do that for packages as well because we store these scripts in VCS.

Then you just run the script and wait for the compiler messages (as with any other script).

Comment: Nice! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as you, but the Oracle JDK version was a problem.
I fixed this problem by changing the source code to match the JDK version. Please check the version.

Comment: I did just like @That young man said and it worked fine. But thank you for reply. :)